# Is either usage of until right?

Tags: grammaticality, differences

"until I have money, I don't care about it" vs "until I don't have money, I don't care about it"?

Comment: They both look OK to me.  Do you have a reason to believe that they aren't?

Comment: The first sentence means, essentially, "Since I don't have money anyway, there is no reason for me to worry about it." The second sentence means, essentially, "Since I still have money anyway, there is no reason for me to worry about it." Both uses of _until_ are meaningful and readily understandable.

Comment: So is the first form incorrect if I'm trying to say I i will only care about money when I don't have it?

Comment: @SvenYargs, if said by a person having sufficient money in their opinion, the first sentence means, "Until I *continue to* have money, I don't care about it".

Comment: @alwayslearning: No. it really doesn't; "Until I continue to have money" would be meaningless. *Until*  does not mean *unless* (as OP appears to think), but neither does it mean *as long as* (as you appear to think).

Comment: @Ashwin: Neither form clearly addresses the question "Under what circumstances will you care about money?" because the "it" at the end of the sentence could refer to any previous subject. For example: "Aren't you worried that the city may raise the tax on sugary drinks?" [Answer 1:] "Until I have money, I don't care about it." {Meaning: I don't have money for sugary drinks anyway, so why should I care that the tax is higher?} [Answer 2: "Until I don't have money, I don't care about it." {Meaning: I have enough money to pay the higher tax, so why should I care that the tax is higher?}

Comment: ...But if the "it" in your sentence refers specifically to money, then "Until I have money, I don't care about it" means "I don't care about money when I don't have money," and "Until I don't have money, I don't care about it" means "I don't care about money as long as I have money."